# Get a specific value from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to get the value a specific value '1222020' which has 'Expiration' as a key:
The 'Expiration' key can be placed at any position.

input :

```
my_list=[{'Key': 'Expiration', 'Value': '12122020'}, {'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'Config Test 2'}]
```

**my solution:**

```
res = [sub['Value'] for sub in my_list if sub['Key'] =='Expiration' ]
print(res)
```

Sometimes the tag 'Expiration' is not present.
How to Handle that and avoid NoneType Object error

Comment: Better in what way? What improvements would you like to see over your current solution?

Comment: The first thing I would suggest, is to reorganize your data structure. It looks like you don't really need a `list` of `dict`, but just a single `dict`. Can you restructure to have something like: `{'Expiration': '12122020', 'Name': 'Config Test 2'}`?

Comment: 'my_list' is actually a returning result from a call to boto3 tags.....So its coming as the input I have given.,also if Sometimes the tag is not present its returning None..So its giving 'NoneType' object error

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this technically belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ since this is a working solution where the OP is asking for a review for efficiency

Comment: OK, but once you have it in that structure, can you reorganize? Something like `{a['Key']: a['Value'] for a in my_list}` would work. And then you only have to iterate over the list once.

Answer (score 0):

If you could re-organize your data like so,

```
custom_dict = {'Expiration': '12122020', 'Name': 'Config Test 2'}
```

Then, you could write the code like this,

```
def get_key_value_from_dictionary_search(dict_data, key_search_phrase, value_search_phrase):
    for k,v in dict_data.items():
       if k is key_search_phrase and v is value_search_phrase:
           return k, v

_k, _v = get_key_value_from_dictionary_search(custom_dict, "Expiration", "12122020")

print("Key : {}\nValue : {}".format(_k, _v))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `Expiration` key isn't present, your `res` evaluates to an empty list. So if you just check for the presence on an empty list, you'll know if `Expiration` was in there to begin with.

```
def get_result(lst, default="99999999"):
    res = [sub['Value'] for sub in lst if sub['Key'] == 'Expiration']
    if res:
        # there is something in the list, so return the first thing
        return res[0]
    else:
        # the list is empty, so Expiration wasn't in lst
        return default

print(get_result(my_list))
```